# JavaScript if button clicked then do something

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I want to have 2 buttons. Button A when clicked appends to Array A. Button B > Array B.

```
var names = ['Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Brenda', 'Lauren', 'Mary'];

<button id="likebutton" type="button">Like</button>
<button id="dislikebutton" type="button">Dislike</button>
function likeOrDislike(){
  var off = true;
  document.getElementById('likeButton').onClick = function(){
    var off = false;
  }
  document.getElementById('dislikeButton').onClick = function(){
    var off = true;
  }
  if(off = false) {
    liked.push(names[0])
    names.splice(0, 1)
  }
  else if (off = true) {
    disliked.push(names[0])
    names.splice(0, 1)
  }
};
```

Then I call the function in this while loop:

```
while(names.length > 0){
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = names[0];
  likeOrDislike()
};
```

Im sure there is a better way to do this then that horrible off variable.
I am getting this error at the moment

> tinder.html:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

Comment: can you also share the name array

Comment: You will get a lot of errors here! Error you have is that button id is `likebutton` and you get element by id `likeButton`

Comment: what is that: `if(off = true)` ? If you want to check, use double or triple equal

Comment: Among many other issues I guess it is `onclick` not `onClick`

Comment: i have amended all errors above and still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use `.addEventListener('click', callback)` or `.onclick` instead of `.onClick`

To compare values use double `==` or triple equals `===`

Don't use `while` in such context. Function will be looping all the time!

Read more about Javascript, for example on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)

I've created working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4Lr34dd/1/) for you.

Here is the code:

```
var names = ['Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Brenda', 'Lauren', 'Mary'],
liked = [],
disliked = [];

showName();
document.getElementById('likeButton').onclick = like;
document.getElementById('dislikeButton').onclick = dislike;

function showName(){
        var name = names[0];
    if(!name){
        name = "The End";
    }    
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = name;
}

function like(){
  liked.push(names[0]);
  names.splice(0, 1);
  showName();
}

function dislike(){
  disliked.push(names[0]);
  names.splice(0, 1);
  showName();
}
```

Comment: This looks good but i get this error: `tinder.html:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`

Comment: @Yoyo it is because in `html` you has another id on button. You has `<button id="likebutton" ..` (all small letters) and in Javascript you are trying to get elment by id `likeButton` (with large 'B' letter)
check [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4Lr34dd/1/)